# How can i build a dynamic order by in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql

NOTE:`p_sort_field & p_order_by are NVARCHAR2` parameters to the stored procedure

```
SELECT ... FROM table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN p_sort_field = 'name' THEN table.Name END ASC
```

This works...

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN p_sort_field = 'name' THEN table.Name ASC END
```

This don't work..

So I need to do soemthing like this

```
SELECT ... FROM table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN p_sort_field = 'name' THEN table.Name END
CASE WHEN p_order_by = 'asc' THEN 
  ASC
ELSE
  DESC
END
```

And this don't work,..  anyone know how I can get this to work?
   I need to append `ASC or DESC` to the `ORDER BY` dynamically.

Thanks in Advance.

## EDIT

I took your advice, it certainly should work.  But with the fully modified stored procedure posted below, my client is getting the below error at: using(OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() { .... }

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1,
  ORA-01003: no statement parsed

As you can see I am attempting to do paging and sorting.  The paging works perfectly and always has, but with this post, I'm trying to integrate sorting (by multiple fields)

Any help solving the above error is much appreciated!

```
PROCEDURE sp_se_paged_list 
(
        p_sort_field           IN VARCHAR2,
        p_order_by             IN VARCHAR2,
        p_page_index           IN NUMBER,
        p_page_size            IN NUMBER,
        p_total_count          OUT NUMBER,
        list_cursor            OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
   IS
   v_select_stmt VARCHAR2(4000);
   BEGIN
       v_select_stmt := 'SELECT * FROM (';     
       v_select_stmt := v_select_stmt || 'SELECT p.*, RowNum rnum FROM(';
       v_select_stmt := v_select_stmt || 'SELECT * FROM se s ORDER BY s.';
       v_select_stmt:= v_select_stmt || p_sort_field;
       v_select_stmt:= v_select_stmt ||' '|| p_order_by;         
       v_select_stmt:= v_select_stmt || ') p';
       v_select_stmt:= v_select_stmt || 'WHERE RowNum <= p_page_index + p_page_size)';
       v_select_stmt:= v_select_stmt || 'WHERE rnum >= p_page_index + 1';
    OPEN list_cursor FOR v_select_stmt;
    SELECT COUNT(*) into p_total_count from se;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR'||SQLERRM);                        
END sp_se_paged_list;
```

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working, just needed to move the 2 IN Params (p_page_index & p_page_size) outside the v_select_stmt string concatenation. Thank you Gaurav, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
--I think your procedure should look like this as shown below 
--Is your p_sort_field is fixed ,then go for your solution of case 
--,but then what is the use of p_sort_fielf as input parameter.  

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE temp
                   (p_sort_field  IN    VARCHAR2
                   ,p_sort_order  IN    VARCHAR2
                   ,p_ref_cur       OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
                   )
 IS
   v_select_stmt  VARCHAR2(2000);
 BEGIN
     v_select_stmt:='SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY table.';
     v_select_stmt := v_select_stmt||p_sort_field ;
     v_select_stmt := v_select_stmt||' '||p_order_by ;

     OPEN p_ref_cur FOR v_select_stmt  ;

 EXCEPTION 
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR'||SQLERRM); 

 END temp;
```